# Changing background-image is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML, with initial `background-image`:

```html
<div id="ffff" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-image: url('/uploads/backroundDefault.jpg')">sddsadsdsa<br>dffdsdfs</div>
```

so far so good. And then:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ffff').css('background-image', 'url(/uploads/lol.png) no-repeat');
});
```

It has no effect

Comment: Any message in the console?

Comment: Do you want to change the background image using only css (with out jQuery) or css (with jquery) ? kindly clear this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`no-repeat` is an invalid `background-image` property. Either remove it:

```
$('#ffff').css('background-image', 'url(/uploads/lol.png)');
```

or set `background` instead:

```
$('#ffff').css('background', 'url(/uploads/lol.png) no-repeat');
```

Comment: cool. The image must be 100% stretched, thats why I let it there

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `no-repeat`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ffff').css('background-image', 'url(/uploads/lol.png)');
});
```

You have given `background-image` not just `background`. So it makes the CSS invalid.